# How to print a space char without type any space and quote in Linux Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

How to print a space char without type any space and quote in Linux Bash shell?

Usually, people can do echo a space character by this

```sh
➜  ~ echo " "
 # output a space character here
```

or

```sh
➜  ~ print " "
 # output a space character here
```

or step further

```sh
➜  ~ echo \\u0020
 # output a space character here
```

But all of those script, needs to input at least one space character when type in the command.

My question is: How to print a space character **without** type in space   character and quote `"` / `'` character in Linux Bash shell?

Likely a pseudo code

```sh
➜  ~ emptychar
 # output a space character here
```

Comment: Currently it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: `echo -e '\u0020'` would for example output a space in unicode, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Puzzles and curiosities are not generally on-topic here. What's the practical problem you're hoping to solve?

Comment: @mashuptwice but there has space character(s) between `echo` and  `\u0020`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm acutally doing a security review for a shell project.

Comment: Anything that would bring this question up should mean it fails the review.

Comment: ...to expand on that: in general, "I can't think of a way to exploit this behavior right now" is not a defense that a poorly-defined behavior is safe. Code that isn't clearly and obviously confined to well-defined behavior should be code that fails review, whether or not you're 100% confident you know how to exploit it immediately.

Comment: BTW, if you mean "without a backslash", it's better to say that than to use "quote character" to refer to backslashes, as a in many contexts "quote character" refers to `"`, `'`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for your so observant reply, I'd create a evidencing enough POC into my review report, because `whoami`/`ls` parameterless commands is not persuasive to hazardous, i need to proof a remote code excuting security bug, or my client might won't fix it

Comment: BTW, in your demo, consider using the `base64 -d` approach shown to run whatever arbitrary code you like. (`IFS=:;cmdA=sh:-c;cmdB=base64:-d;$cmdA<<<$($cmdB<<<...)`, where `...` is the base64 encoding of any shell command or pipeline you choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoiding spaces *and backslashes*

```
IFS=:;cmd=base64:-d;$cmd<<<IA==
```

...using hexdump to demonstrate that this produces a space in output:

```
$ IFS=:;cmd=base64:-d;$cmd<<<IA== | hexdump -C
00000000  20                                                | |
00000001
```

---

#### Avoiding Spaces

Using `IFS` to set a non-space character to be treated as a field separator can be leveraged here:

```
IFS=:;var=printf:%b:\x20;$var
```

Likewise, demonstrating output:

```
$ IFS=:;var=printf:%b:\\x20;$var | hexdump -C
00000000  20                                                | |
00000001
```